# ASP.NET MVC: Can't figure out what VirtualPath is?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionresult, virtual-path

I have a View that displays a list of images and i am now trying to get it to display the images as thumbnails.  Well, i'm pretty sure i got most of it right using VirtualPath's from a custom ActionResult although i can't seem to figure out what it is making the VirtualPath url??  BTW, i'm using XML to store the data from the images instead of SQL.  Here is my code:

Code from my custom ActionResult:

```
public class ThumbnailResult : ActionResult
{
    public ThumbnailResult(string virtualPath)
    {
        this.VirtualPath = virtualPath;
    }

    public string VirtualPath { get; set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/bmp";

        string fullFileName =
            context.HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Galleries/WhereConfusionMeetsConcrete/" + VirtualPath);
        using (System.Drawing.Image photoImg =
            System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fullFileName))
        {
            using (System.Drawing.Image thumbPhoto =
                photoImg.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, null, new System.IntPtr()))
            {
                using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                {
                    thumbPhoto.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    context.HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
                    context.HttpContext.Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code for my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Thumbnail(string id)
{
    return new ThumbnailResult(id);
}
```

Code for my View:

```
<% foreach (var image in ViewData.Model) { %>

<a href="../Galleries/TestGallery1/<%= image.Path %>"><img src="../Galleries/TestGallery1/thumbnail/<%= image.Path %>" alt="<%= image.Caption %>" /></a>
<br /><br /><%= image.Caption %><br /><br /><br />

<% } %>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!  Let me know of any questions you have as well. :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you are using the `VirtualPath` string member in the `ThumbnailResult` custom action to identify the last portion of the image url. So for example if your site is located at `c:\wwwroot\Galleries\WhereConfusionMeetsConcrete` and the image files are located inside this folder like `image1.bmp`, `image2.bmp`, ... you could only pass the image filename to the custom action result constructor which is called in the controller action and passed the `id` parameter. So in order to show a thumbnail for `image1.bmp` in your view you could do this:

```
<img src="<%= Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "home", action = "Thumbnail", id = "image1.bmp" }) %>" alt="" />
```

Of course this assumes that you have a default route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```